# Angular - Use a service to insert a component intro another one

Tags: angular, angular-components

So I want to be able to pass a component to a service, then the service will insert this component and pass the data into another one, example:

app.component: Need to show info on aside, calls aside.show(Component, data)
aside.service: Recieves the component and the data and inserts them into aside.generic.

Just by calling aside.service and passing some params to show the aside, if you use ngx-bootstrap I want it to work on the lines of how modals work there.

Comment: Have you taken a look at `@angular/cdk`? I think portals can make your life easier: https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview

Comment: @jpavel Haven't looked at that, at a first glance it looks like it will solve my problem, thanks! will update on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to add dynamic component :

So to add dynamic component by using service you can do like this:

In your `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Service } from './service'
import { DynamicComponent } from './dynamic.component'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
   constructor(public service: Service, public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
  }
  add(){
    this.service.setRootViewContainerRef(this.viewContainerRef);
    this.service.addDynamicComponent()
  }
}
```

and in your `service.ts`:

```
import {
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  Injectable,
  Inject,
  ReflectiveInjector
} from '@angular/core'

import { DynamicComponent } from './dynamic.component'

@Injectable()
export class Service {
  rootViewContainer:any;

  constructor(private factoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  public setRootViewContainerRef(viewContainerRef) {
    this.rootViewContainer = viewContainerRef
  }

  public addDynamicComponent() {
    const factory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent)
    const component = factory.create(this.rootViewContainer.parentInjector)

    this.rootViewContainer.insert(component.hostView)
  }

}
```

I have created a working stackblitz url which does the same :

Below is the link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-component-j2m3c1?file=app%2Fservice.ts

This should give you a fair idea about how to implement it in your specific case

Comment: Exactly what I was looking at, that stackblitz link is the cherry on top, thanks Amrit!